# Problem while installation of Flutter in MacOS

Tags: android, macos, flutter, android-studio, terminal

After installing the flutter package., while making changes through the Terminal.,and facing issues. Always getting the error as shown below.

Could anyone please resolve this issue.

```
Unhandled exception:
Exception: Flutter failed to create a directory at "/Users/sabhinav/.config/flutter". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _throwFileSystemException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:749:3)
#2      _handlePosixException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:697:3)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:561:7)
#4      ErrorHandlingDirectory.createSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:408:12)
#5      new Config (package:flutter_tools/src/base/config.dart:33:17)
#6      new _DefaultPersistentToolState (package:flutter_tools/src/persistent_tool_state.dart:65:18)
#7      new PersistentToolState (package:flutter_tools/src/persistent_tool_state.dart:21:9)
#8      runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:257:34)
#9      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:41)
#10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:311:23)
#11     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#12     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#13     PersistentToolState.instance (package:flutter_tools/src/persistent_tool_state.dart:35:54)
#14     persistentToolState (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:53:68)
#15     _defaultBotDetector (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:112:24)
#16     _defaultBotDetector (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart)
#17     botDetector (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:115:62)
#18     isRunningOnBot (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:117:36)
#19     runInContext.runnerWrapper (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:69:34)
#20     runInContext.runnerWrapper (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:68:28)
#21     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:29)
#22     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:7)
#23     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
#24     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
#25     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1788:10)
#26     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1710:10)
#27     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:18)
#28     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:24)
#29     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:47:10)
#30     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:9)
#31     main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/k/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#32     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:281:32)
#33     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

Comment: What's the read/write permission of "/Users/sabhinav/.config/flutter"? Try running `ls -l /Users/sabhinav/.config` to see the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The .config folder is supposed to be owned by the user. It appears that the ownership got changed to system by mistake on your machine.

To restore the default permission, **execute the following command**:

```
$ sudo chown -R <username> .config
```

When prompted for a password, enter your login password.

**The above sudo command gives access to .config files to the Admin.**

Substitute  with your username.

To determine your username, execute the following command and observe the output.

```
$ whoami
```

After this process..,

Execute the following command :

```
flutter --version
```

Run the following command to see if there are any dependencies you need to install to complete the setup:

```
flutter doctor
```

You'll be completed with the Flutter Installation..!

Answer (score 0):

Terminal needs full disk access to write into the flutter folder.

Go to System Settings -> FullDiskAccess -> Terminal (yes). This should solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).